# how to shutdown the applications running on the Android Things?

Tags: android, android-things

I'm new for the Android Things, and I have a question for it.

I find that an Application will be running automatically When I restart the ResPi3 with Android Things, But I don't want it to do this.

Then I press the 'ESC', the app will be broke down but it will be running again and again....... so, I want to know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<!-- Launch activity automatically on boot -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

section from your app main Activity description in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks~It's really useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use adb to remove the app using the command.

```
adb uninstall <app.package.name>
```

Comment: I have get what I want from your answer.Thank you very much~